# Can't get what I want using SQL subquery

Tags: sql, database, oracle

There are 2 tables with the following columns:
TABLE1

```
++++++++++++++++  
user_id NUMBER  
status_change_date DATE
```

TABLE2

```
++++++++++++++++  
user_id NUMBER  
count NUMBER  
status VARCHAR(10)  
enter_date DATE
```

What I want is to find the rows in table1 which the user's status_change_date is not equal to the "user's last enter_date with status 'closed'".

I wrote the following SQL

```
SELECT * FROM table1 a WHERE status_change_date <>  
(SELECT max(enter_date) FROM table2 b 
WHERE a.user_id = b.user_id AND b.status='closed');
```

However, the result is a list user_id that the status_change_date is equal to the last enter_date with status 'closed'.

Comment: could you give us an example data?

Comment: You may not think it but you aren't actually checking to see that the user_ids match in the outer query. Think of it this way, you are asking, "First build a list of all of the maximum enter_dates where the user_id in table b is in table a, then show me all of the rows from table a where the date isn't in that list".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM table1 T JOIN Table2 S ON
T.status_change_date <> max(S.enter_date) AND
T.user_id = S.user_id
WHERE S.status= 'closed'
```